# MongoDB - Efficient backup

Tags: azure, mongodb, database-backup, parse-server

I have an application running on a `Parse Server` and another server where MongoDB runs. Both VMs are under `Azure` (Ubuntu VMs). A few weeks back, I wrote a db backup `bash` script which is run by `crontab` once a day, every day.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

MONGO_DATABASE="db"
MONGO_HOST="127.0.0.1"
MONGO_PORT="portNo"
TIMESTAMP=`date +%d-%m-%Y--%H:%M:%S`
MONGODUMP_PATH="/usr/bin/mongodump"
BACKUPS_DIR="/datadrive/mongodb/backups/"
BACKUP_NAME="$TIMESTAMP"

# mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncLock())"
# $MONGODUMP_PATH -h $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT -d $MONGO_DATABASE
sudo $MONGODUMP_PATH -d $MONGO_DATABASE
# mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncUnlock())"

sudo mv dump $BACKUP_NAME
sudo tar -zcvf $BACKUPS_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME.tgz $BACKUP_NAME
sudo rm -rf $BACKUP_NAME
sudo find $BACKUPS_DIR/ -type f -mtime +0 -name '*.tgz' -delete
```

Ever since, I noticed a huge increment on the server's resources consumption, which costs twice as much than without the backup system!

My db's size is about 7GB and growing! What should I do in order to have a backup system that's CPU or otherwise efficient?

Comment: incremental backups can be great, but for mongodb the issue is tricky. there isnt really a convenient way to do it without paying for expensive services (mongodb cloud) or writing your own scripts (https://tech.willhaben.at/mongodb-incremental-backups-dff4c8f54d58)

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do in order to have a backup system that's CPU or
>   otherwise efficient?

Maybe you can deploy Mongodb [replica sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/), then use another VM to run backup crontab.

Also, you can run crontab in free time.

Comment: What about any paid services? Are there any?

Comment: @SotirisKaniras Maybe you can use Azure backup to backup that disk every day.

Comment: Hi Jason, I would like utilize Azure backup service that should backup mongodb replicaset.  Could you please highlight some points on that how to proceed.  I am new to azure and would like to backup the mongodb via azure.